# error when i run flutter for the first time on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, flutter

I start a new project with intellij idea and flutter but when click create it's give me error

[image: the error in intillj idea]
and this's the log of the error

Flutter crash report; please file at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

### command

```
flutter --no-color create --template app --description A new Flutter project. --org com.example untitled6
```

### exception

```
FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'C:\Users\Hussam\IdeaProjects\untitled6\.idea\libraries' (OS Error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
, errno = 183)
```

logs

```
bash
#0      _Directory.createSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:140:7)
#1      _File.createSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:280:14)
#2      ForwardingFile.createSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:24:16)
#3      Template.render.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/template.dart:168:28)
#4      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
#5      Template.render (package:flutter_tools/src/template.dart:132:24)
#6      CreateCommand._renderTemplate (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/create.dart:667:21)
#7      CreateCommand._generateApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/create.dart:578:23)
#8      CreateCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/create.dart:429:37) <asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:615:18)
#10     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#11     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#12     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#13     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#14     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#15     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#16     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#17     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)
#18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#20     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#21     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#22     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#23     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#24     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#25     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:175:5)
```

### flutter doctor

```
console
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.535], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (12 days ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Hussam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 41.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4
    • Flutter plugin version 42.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 193.5731

[!] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Hussam\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

please someone tell me what I should do and what's the problem

Comment: From the information you shared we can only really use the exception "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." Is it a permissions problem?

Comment: how I can fix it ?

Comment: If it's a permissions problem I won't be able to help you. You have to fix it on your machine.

Comment: some one tell me is about the name of the project so I delete it  and create a new one with different name but still get the same error but I really I don't understand why could be permission problem because there's no "permission " word in the line that you copied from the log

Answer (score 0):

Delete your current app folder and create it once again.
It works in my case and I am using vscode ide.